# Flutter unit tests for Sentry

Tags: flutter, unit-testing, dart, sentry

Is there a way to write unit tests for [Sentry](https://pub.dev/packages/sentry_flutter) in Flutter?

I have a function that takes in a set of inputs and reports to Sentry

```dart
reportError({...}){
  Sentry.captureException(stackTrace, stackTrace: stackTrace, hint: hint);
}
```

And I want to write a unit test for the same

```dart
  test('sends to sentry', () {
      reportError(
        hint: 'error',
        response: Response(
          json.encode(<String, dynamic>{'message': '4: error'}),
          401,
        ),
      );
    });
```

The question is, how do I verify that the error was logged?

Answer (score 1):

You can set a custom mock client in tests using `Sentry.bindClient()` - see how Sentry does it in its unit tests here: https://github.com/getsentry/sentry-dart/blob/02419b742e39fd070faa613151db22e5b8c9f041/dart/test/sentry_test.dart